# 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, matrix

My code for printing a matrix in a square form is as follows:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    line = "\t|"+str(A[i][0])
    for j in range(1, len(A[i])):
        line = line + "\t" + str(A[i][j])
    line = line + "|"
    print(line)
```

where A is the list [22, 38, 30, 58, 34, 69]

It should look like

|22     38|

|30     58|

|34     69|

It keeps returning
'int' object is not subscriptable
for the line in the code:

```
    line = "\t|"+str(A[i][0])
```

how do i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

`A` is a list--a one-dimensional array. `A[0]` is an `int`, which is not subscriptable. Hence your error.

It is more natural in python to represent a matrix as a two-dimensional list, e.g.:

```
A = [[22, 38], [30, 58], [34, 69]]
```

or

```
A = [[22, 30, 34], [38, 58, 69]]
```

If you do this your code will work, although it would be better to use code like this:

```
def print_matrix(M):
    for N in M:
        print("|{}|".format('\t'.join(str(O) for O in N)))

print_matrix(A)
```

Or even just:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(A)
```

If you are tied to your single-dimensionality for A, you can print it like so:

```
def print_list_matrix(M, width):
    for i, j in zip(range(0, len(M), width), range(skip, len(M)+width, width)):
        print('|{}|'.format("\t".join(str(O) for O in M[i:j])))
```

Or like this:

```
def print_list_matrix(M, width):
    for i in range(0, len(M), width):
        print('|{}|'.format("\t".join(str(O) for O in M[i:i+width])))
```

Or if you want to avoid slicing:

```
from itertools import izip

def grouper(seq, size):
    iters = [iter(seq)] * size
    return izip(*iters)

def print_list_matrix(M, width):
    for N in grouper(M, width):
        print('|{}|'.format("\t".join(str(O) for O in N)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you trying to use plain list as matrix, you can either make it not plain or use correct indexing. For example you can try something like this:

```
A = [22, 38, 30, 58, 34, 69]
size = 2 # put here the exact number of values within each row you want

for i in range(0, len(A), size):
    print '\t'.join(map(str, res[i:i+size]))
```

Comment: +1 Given the OP's input was a 1-dimensional array, this is the appropriate implementation to output that array as a matrix IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

the difficulty in python is that you cannot use two dimension to specify lists. only a single dimension is allowed. so

> A[0]=22

but

> A[0][1]

throws error. To specify double subscripts, dictionaries can be used

Comment: I'm not sure that your point about double subscripting makes sense. It's perfectly legal to index into a list of lists with `A[0][1]`. The issue the questioner seems to be having is that he's using a simple one-dimensional list of values, rather than a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

What language?

Regardless,

I assume your input is *meant* to be a 2 dimensional array, but it is only a 1 dimensional array.  Or that your code is *meant* to process a 1 dimensional array to make it "look" 2 dimensional.

But as it is, your code is attempting to process a 2 dimensional array that does not exist, as your input array is 1 dimensional.

If this answer doesn't give you enough to correct, then please include the language as a tag and code in your original question (edit it) and then add a comment to @Sepster and I'll look again.

EDIT: Missed OP had stated *where A is the list [22, 38, 30, 58, 34, 69]*.